# Get a string from another column and use to name Series column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe with columns (among other columns, but these are the import ones)

```
    Category  Part Number  observed
0  Engine     RJ45         2013-01-01    0
                           2014-01-01    0
```

Where Part Number is a string and Observed is a pandas Series.

I want to set every Observed Series .name attribute to the Part Number in the same row.

Whats the easiest way to go about this while keeping the order of both the DataFrame and Series intact?

I am hoping to get it like this

```
    Category  Part Number  observed
0  Engine     RJ45         2013-01-01    0
                           2014-01-01    0
                           name: RJ45 dtype: int64
```

I just want to set observed.name = RJ45, but for every row of the dataframe, using the part number in that row.

Comment: Can you post the exact desired output instead of explaining it?

Comment: More specifically, what you've described doesn't make sense.  That's ok because it not making sense is probably why you're asking a question.  However, we can't help make sense of it unless you help us to understand.  That means you need to do more work demonstrating what you're trying to to.

Comment: You are correct that this does not make sense.